# Noise filtering in audio

Tags: filtering, sound, signal-processing

I was given audio with white Gaussian noise and i have to implement two types of filter: Rectangle and Triangle that filter out redundant frequencies and reduce the amount of noise

Here is the code for the audio with the noise

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
 Print["Original File:"]
 suite = Import["bach_suite_cello.mp3"] 
suite // Options; 
samples = AudioData[AudioTrim[suite, {2, 13}]][[1]]; 
Print["44k Sampling:"]
 samples44k = Audio[samples, SampleRate -> 44100]
 audioData44k = Flatten[AudioData[samples44k]];
 samples44kWithNoise = audioData44k + RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 0.1], Length[audioData44k]]; 
audioWithNoise = Audio[samples44kWithNoise]
```

Here's a link to the original audio  [bach suite cello](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1prweT95Mo0).

So i want to filter out the noise using Rectangle and Triangle filters

Thanks for all those who help

Answer (score 4):

```
a = ExampleData[{"Audio", "Clapping"}, "Audio"]
(* NOTE: this is mono data.
 For stereo you must apply filtering to both channels [[1]] and [[2]] *)
dat = AudioData[a][[1]];

(* Convolve with your own kernels *)
rectangleFiltered = ListConvolve[{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}/7., dat];
triangleFiltered = ListConvolve[{1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1}/16., dat];
Audio[rectangleFiltered, SampleRate -> AudioSampleRate[a]]
Audio[triangleFiltered, SampleRate -> AudioSampleRate[a]]

(* See also: Mathematica's built in filtering *)
MeanFilter[a,7]
```

Comment: Can you tell me how I get my kernels?  Thanks for the help .

Comment: That's what these are: `{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}/7.` and `{1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1}/16.`. I've also normalized them hence the `/7` and `/16`. The first is flat  (rectangular) and the second runs up and then back down (triangular).